# How to show data use DataTables with Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, datatables

I'm try to implement a simple Webpage that can show some data from MySql by using Node.js server, here is my Server.js code:

```
app.get('/Result'),function(req,res){
   var conn=mysql.createConnection(setting);
   conn.query('select*from users',function(err,rows){
   if (err) throw err;

   //***********Do something
   //Data in rows
   }

});
```

Now I get the JSON format data in "rows" and want show on page use DataTables,
I had try to use a single Table.html file then use fs.readFile but that not I want, or search for some examples but still no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [console.table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/console.table) npm package for this purpose

Comment: Thank you sir, I'll try that :)